# The 「と」 conditional to be used as "when"?

Tags: translation, meaning, particle-と

i'm not entirely sure but remember that conditionals could be used to also mean "when" when in is that the case here?

> ゲームを愛する引き篭もり少年・佐藤（さとう）和真（かずま）の人生は、あっけなく幕を閉じた・・・・・・はずだったが、目を覚ます**と**目の前に女神と名乗る美少女が。

would I be correct in translating the whole sentence as some along the lines of "gaming loving shut-in, satou kazuma's life life had the curtains closed too soon..... that was how it was supposed to be but, **when** he awoke, before his eyes was beautiful girl calling herself a goddess" ?

it doesn't make much sense to mean *if* here but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of this sentence is a bit strange to me (maybe I'm just confused by punctuation).

Anyway, I guess that the *と* you are discussing here is used just as in the usual すると type of construction (plain verb + と). So, in this case, I think that it's OK to translate it with *when* in English, as this form generally describes a cause/effect kind of relationship.

Breaking it down in a very literal way, that part of the sentence probably could be translated as:

*(subject) opens/opened (his/her) eyes **and** (consequence)*.

Of course, in a more standard English we would probably change this structure using *when*:

***when*** (subject) opens/opened (his/her) eyes (consequence),

which basically bears the same idea of cause/effect. I think this article might be also useful:

http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/02/10/the-real-story-on-three-japanese-conditionals-%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%80%81%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%80%81%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0-suru-to-shitara-sureba/

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much. This helps a lot.